# undefined local variable or method ` ' for main:Object

Tags: ruby, whitespace

Sometimes, the following causes a strange bug:

```
> nil || 4
NameError: undefined local variable or method ` 4' for main:Object

> nil || []
NameError: undefined local variable or method ` ' for main:Object
```

What is the reason?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are accidentally typing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> on your Mac, which produces a [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). Ruby does not consider this as whitespace, but as part of a variable name. It then complains that the variable does not exist.

[Some people like to remap <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to <kbd>Space</kbd> in order to prevent this typo.](https://superuser.com/questions/78245/how-to-disable-the-option-space-key-combination-for-non-breaking-spaces)

I personally like to highlight invisible characters in my text editor, so I notice the typo immediately.

Comment: Good idea, Alt+Space indeed causes an error like this. It occurs also as part of an application, maybe the source code contains an Alt+Space as well. Is it possible to make it visible somehow?

Comment: `grep ' ' -R .` (type alt+space in between the single quotes)

Comment: Thanks. This is a tricky bug, you need to press "Alt" on a Mac to produce a "|", at least on German keyboards. It is easily to type accidentally "Alt+Space" for the following space.

Comment: I'm German too, that’s probably the reason why I know this error message so well ;-)

Comment: For those of you using VScode and can't find (alt/option+space) there are extensions: [non-breaking space highlighter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=viktorzetterstrom.non-breaking-space-highlighter&ssr=false#overview), [fix irregular white spaces](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=karlito40.fix-irregular-whitespace)

Answer (score 2):

I, for one, got a pretty annoying version of this error from a code file that someone else had written. It kept complaining about an undefined space on a line but there was nothing on it. You could place your cursor on the line and it'd only land on the first place a character could go on. Also, no characters(not even space) highlighted on the line after changing editor preferences. Couldn't grep for it either with option-space on a mac.

Finally resolved by reformatting code from the IDE options. It magically introduced extra new lines in the places ruby was complaining about. Just deleted those and voila, no more errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I copied some unsupported quote characters from somewhere.

```
# does not work
$: << File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), ‘..’, ‘lib’)

# works (note ‘’ vs '')
$: << File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib')
```